# XCode3 - relationship between Library Search Paths and project Frameworks

Tags: c++, xcode, xcode3.2

As a new MAc developer coming from VS I don't really 'get' what a framework is. If I add a framework to my project, does this automatically mean the headers should be found when I do `#include <SomeFile.h>`?

I seem to be finding in some cases I have to add header search paths as well. Does that mean the framework isn't working right?

Answer (score 4):

As defined by the [Apple Conceptual Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPFrameworks/Concepts/WhatAreFrameworks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002303-BBCEIJFI):

> A framework is a hierarchical directory that encapsulates shared
>   resources, such as a dynamic shared library, nib files, image files,
>   localized strings, header files, and reference documentation in a
>   single package.

In other words, it is a compilation of resources that can be utilized by one or more applications, and it is not an application by itself.

Detailed by the [Apple Conceptual Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPFrameworks/Tasks/IncludingFrameworks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002257-BAJJBBHJ):

> You include framework header files in your code using the `#include`
>   directive. If you are working in Objective-C, you may use the
>   `#import` directive instead of the `#include` directive. The two
>   directives have the same basic results. but the `#import` directive
>   guarantees that the same header file is never included more than once.
>   There are two ways for including framework headers:
>
> ```
> #include <Framework_name/Header_filename.h>
> #import <Framework_name/Header_filename.h>
> ```
>
> In both cases, **Framework_name** is the name of the framework and
>   **Header_filename** is the name of a header file in that framework or in one of its subframeworks.
>
> When including framework header files, it is traditional to include
>   only the master framework header file. The master header file is the
>   header file whose name matches the name of the framework. For example,
>   the Address Book framework has a master header file with the name
>   `AddressBook.h`.

To include custom frameworks:

> If your project links to frameworks that are not included in any of
>   the standard locations, you must explicitly specify the location of
>   that framework before Xcode can locate its header files. To specify
>   the location of such a framework, add the directory containing the
>   framework to the [“Framework Search Paths” option of your Xcode
>   project](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/XcodeBuildSettingRef/1-Build_Setting_Reference/build_setting_ref.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003931-CH3-SW87). Xcode passes this list of directories to the compiler and
>   linker, which both use the list to search for the framework resources.

Answer (score 3):

If the framework is properly written, it contains the headers as well as the actual linkable (binary) file. The compiler (GCC formerly, LLVM-clang recently) recognizes framework paths and knows automatically where to search for framework headers. There are some corner cases though:

1. If you don't add a framework, but really a traditional Unix library (libsqlite3.dylib, libxml2.dylib etc.) from /usr/lib. Then it may be the case that the library has a separate (unstandard) include path; this is common, for example, in the case of glib. You have to add /usr/include/glib-2.0 to your header search path in this case.
2. The opposite case: when you encounter some of the "Umbrella" frameworks (for example, Core Audio is split up into small subframeworks, such as AudioToolbox.framework etc.), then that particular framework doesn't contain a linkable dynamic library, only headers.

I hope this helps.